# Handling different user sessions in same browser in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-security, session-cookies

I have a spring mvc application in which an admin can create and update users info and open their respective user windows in the same browser. But when an admin opens one user session in one tab and then tries to open another user session in another tab it gives error saying one active session already exists. How can we enable the admin to play with different users with their individual sessions in the same browser and different tabs? Is there any way by which we can handle these sessions

Comment: As long as you keep the authentication token (i.e. `SESSIONID`) in a cookie from same domain, it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks, is there any alternative to have this solved?

Comment: This is more of a client side issue. Could it be handled in one user session? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Basically admin has rights to update user details which can be of different countries, so if he opens a user session/tab for one country and parallely he wants to open a user session/tab of another country

Comment: How can we handle at client side?

Comment: Opening a users details doen't mean user session. You have wrong perception.  It is unclear what you are trying to ask. **admin opens one user session in one tab and then tries to open another user session in another tab**. In your company previous developer might have implemented this functionality where only one user is allowed to edit at a time. Debug current implementation and understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think when user is open session web app give some id active browser tab for window object for example `$window.name = "cliendId"`

and your spring app when user login send this window id by web and and handle with spring security

```
public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetails extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomWebAuthenticationDetails.class);

    private final String clientid;

    CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        clientid = request.getHeader("clientid");

        log.debug("User Agent {}", request.getHeader("User-Agent"));
    }

    public String getClientid() {
        return clientid;
    }

}
```

and configure

```
@Component
public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource implements AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, WebAuthenticationDetails> {
    @Override
    public WebAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(final HttpServletRequest context) {
        return new CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(context);
    }
}
```

and now manage or list this session ids by user and when user open new session same tab alert or kill sessions with  write own security filter and implement security filter chain manage each request